# Finding coordinates relative to basis (Linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

The set
$V$ = {$(a + 2b + 3c, 3a + b + 4c, 4a + 3b + 7c) : a, b, c ∈ R$} 
forms a subspace of $R^3$

(a) Show that $S$ = {$(1, 3, 4),(2, 1, 3),(3, 4, 7)$} is a spanning set for $V$ .

(b) Find a subset of $S$ which is a basis for $V$ . Hence find the dimension of $V$ .

(c) Let B be the basis from part (b). Find $[v]_B$ where $v = (3, 2, 5)$.

(d) Find the vector $w = (a, b, c)$ in $R^3$
such that $[w]_B = \begin{bmatrix}3\\5\end{bmatrix}$

Question $a$ is pretty straightforward. For question $b$, I believe the basis is {$(1,3,4),(2,1,3)$}. I got this after writing the vectors as columns in a matrix and from rref. And I believe the dimension is 2.

For questions $c$ and $d$, I'm unsure where to begin, given that equating the basis vectors to v wouldn't give the bottom value of $[v]_B$. I would really appreciate some help for questions (c) and (d)

Comment: $[v]_B = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ means that $v = x\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\4\end{bmatrix} + y\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You can write $(a+2b+3c,3a+b+4c,4a+3b+7c)$ as $(a,3a,4a)+(2b,b,3b)+(3c,4c,7c)$ that is equal to $a(1,3,4)+b(2,1,3)+c(3,4,7)$ and as $a,b,c$ are arbitrary, so you conclude that $\{(1,3,4),(2,1,3),(3,4,7)\}$ spans $V$.

b) To found a basis you can form a matrix with the vectors $\{(1,3,4),(2,1,3),(3,4,7)\}$ and apply echelon method to it, because the echelon method is actualy applying fundamental operations to the vectors, the result is the same spanned space.

c) To find $[v]_B$ is to find scalars $a$ and $b$ such that $[v]_B= a v_1+ bv_2$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the basis vectors found in b), so you must solve a linear system given by

$(3,2,5)=a (v_{1_1},v_{1_2},v_{1_3})+b (v_{2_1},v_{2_2},v_{2_3})$

where $v_1=(v_{1_1},v_{1_2},v_{1_3})$ and $v_2=(v_{2_1},v_{2_2},v_{2_3})$

sorry for the notation. I'm doing it generically, because I don't really know the values of $v_1$ and $v_2$, but they are the vectors you found in b).

So, solving the system and finding $a$ and $b$ then you get $[v]_B=[a b]_B$

d) Here you use the same linear system that you used in c), but now you have $a$ and $b$.

Is it clear? I hope I've been able to help you

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that you already got a) and b)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the late reply